# Find text that appears multiple times (look for string most right in sheet) and copy

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the text "Locked" within Sheet1.

As the number of sales each week are locked down, the text "Locked" will appear in row 3.  The previous week's will all remain, therefore I am looking for code to find the "Locked" that appears **most right** in row 3.

Once that cell is detected I need to offset the selection to row 5 (same column) and copy to the bottom of the table.

The selection then needs to be pasted in cell M5.

If any more information is required, happy to provide.

```
Columns(13).ClearContents

Cells.Find(What:="LOCKED", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Copy
Columns(13).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Any code so far you tried?

Comment: People here are happy to help but this forum is not a programming service where you state your requirements and debugged ready-to-use code is returned. You need to prove that you have made efforts to find the solution yourself and that includes showing your code so far.
For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why the code I have tried hasn't attached.  I'll try again.

Comment: And what is wrong with your code, what error does it give, or does it give unexpected output?

Comment: I'm looking to find the furthest column to the right containing "LOCKED"  within row 3, however just now it just looks for the next cell containing "LOCKED".  Does that make sense?

Comment: You should do a search for "lastrow" that is a commonly used concept in vba programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will achieve what you are wanting:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
Dim rng As Range

ws.Columns(13).ClearContents
'clear contents of Column M

Set rng = ws.Rows("3:3").Find(What:="LOCKED", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'set the rng variable to the last "LOCKED" found in Row 3

If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'if found
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data in that column
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, rng.Column), ws.Cells(LastRow, rng.Column)).Copy
    'copy from row 3 to last row in found column
    ws.Range("M5").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'paste into Range M5
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Escape the copied range
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Xabier This worked perfectly! I'm still getting the hang of VBA, I appreciate the help!